# Authorize.Net module missing Login Id and Key option - Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, payment-gateway, payment, authorize.net, prestashop-1.6

I recently started working on Prestashop. Today, I installed the Authorize.Net module and i am unable to find the options to add Login ID and Key on configuration page. Below is what I can see on configuration page.

[image]

I already have account on Authorize.Net. Kindly guide me whats going wrong and where I can put the Login ID and Key to activate Authorize.Net on my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on it for days, the issue seems to be an idiotic mistake. But answering because that might help someone who just get started with Prestashop.

The module wasn't working with the store currency i set(PKR in my case). When i put USD dollars, for no reason but in frustration, it worked because PKR is not supported by Authorize.Net.

But still i think when setting the currency that is not supported by Authorize.NET we should have some sort of error on configuration page to notify the site admin atleast. So please cross check if you set the store currency that is supported by Authorize.NET.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Modules and then find the module called "Authorize.net AIM (Advanced Integration Method)", then click the Configure button on the right. Then you'll be presented with a screen where  you can enter your Login ID and key.

Comment: Thanks but i have pasted the image url. I am talking about that particular screen infact.